# How does Twitter App in Android cache/store tweets in the listview?

Tags: android, caching

In Twitter Android App, Once the listview is populated with tweets/items downloaded from server, it never again talks to server to fetch them again. Even if you kill the app and start it again, it still retrieves the same old data.How does twitter store this much of data. Is it using database, storing all downloaded data in a file or caching.

In  my app , i have  a similar requirement.For now i store the downloaded listview data in a file and then read it whenever the app is started afresh.Is there a better approach or a followed patter for this.
Thank You.

Comment: Take a look at SQLLite ;)

Comment: @user1281750 How is the performance of SQLLite.You think Twitter is using the same technique? As i have already said i am storing the data in a file, do you think SQLLite would be a better solution.I havent seen any performance issues yet with File Storage as my is no big than 20 items.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to save/persist data on clientside. These being:

1. SharedPreferences (not ideal with requirements)
2. File I/O
3. SQLLite database

As far as I know there isn't a big difference is performance between file-I/O and SQLLite. But SQLLite has a lot of other advantages.

1. You can query the database, this is more easy then writing it yourself with file-I/O
2. Manipulation of data is for more easy and less painful (delete/update records etc)
3. Supports relations between data!

Bottom line, go for SQLLite, it seems more work to setup but you will benefit from this in the future.

Comment: For my specific requirement, saving a file does the job. But what i would like to know is about 'Cache' Technique in HTTP Responses. Is it enabled by default,how does it work actually? Any tutorials about that?

Comment: All depends on architecture of your backend system. E.g. If they follow the  REST conventions then they would have implemented the 304 - NOT MODIFIED header when you perform a GET request with If-Modified-Since. The best way to learn about these techniques is reading books and learning by hand, and most of the time you should implement these yourself, sometimes you can use a library (all depending on your backend interaction/architecture)